# How to trigger all feature branches from Travis CI using github?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have Github public account and repo and Travis CI integration. Everything is OK but I want Travis CI to trigger not only when have changes in the master but also in specific all feature branches. My feature branches has the following structure:

```
- feature/spring-boot-properties
- feature/add-db-source
```

And my **.travis.yml** file:

```
sudo: false

language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - oraclejdk7


env:
  global:
    - MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"
    - JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx256m"

cache:
  directories:
  - $HOME/.m2

branches:
  only:
    - master
    - feature/spring-boot-properties
    - feature/add-db-source


notifications:
  email: false

script: mvn clean install
```

Is there any pattern for specific branch name specification?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build#Building-Specific-Branches? It shows using regular expressions to match branches/tags.

Comment: I tried with     - /^feature.*$/ in the yml in the master and in the feature branch but only when have changes from the master the build is triggered.

Comment: Is a `.travis.yml` file present in your feature branches?

Comment: @Bovarysme yes but with what in its content?

Comment: @Xelian probably the same contents as the one in master?

Answer (score 2):

In my .travis.yml file in master and in evry feature branch I added:

```
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - /^feature.*$/
```

And now when make changes in new feature branch new job is triggered.

[image]